# Outlook takes over Window focus

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab, window-focus

I recently upgraded Office 2013 to v 2019 and ever since, Windows 10 Pro (64bit) loses its current window focus to Outlook.  It seems to happen somewhat randomly, every 5-7 minutes.  Generally, while I'm typing in another program, (Word, etc.) I will suddenly find that I can't type in the application.  Then about 5 minutes later an Outlook reminder screen will pop up with a couple of seemingly random characters as the appointment title.  After it happened a couple of times, I began to recognize certain characters from the sentence or formula I was typing as the title of the appointment.  It doesn't always create an Outlook appointment, but most of the time it does.  In the time it took me to write this it happened 3x.  I then have to alt-tab to refocus the input on the correct screen.

Any ideas as to what is causing this to happen?  I haven't installed anything else recently, only the upgrade to Office 2019 (not Office 365).  Is this just Microsoft's attempt to get me into their subscription service?

Comment: Not that I love MS.. but this sounds like a Virus or similar.  Identify and remove ANYTHING running in the background.  SOMETHING is doing this.. and Microsoft isn't it.

Comment: I thought that too, but I haven't installed anything nor opened any "You've Won the Lotery!"[sic] emails.  I downloaded Window Focus Logger which monitors any change in focus and the offending application; it's definitely Outlook that is the guilty party.  It takes over keyboard focus and user interface focus.  And it just did it again as I was typing this.

If I could upload a screenshot of the logger I would.

Comment: Not saying that it is this.. but outlook is also capable of hosting 3rd party plugins.